# When I compressed glb file with gltf-pipeline I got an error:message: 'Error: Draco encoding failed.'

Tags: node.js

I tried:

```
gltf-pipeline -i car.glb -o car-processed.glb -d
```

I got error:

```
Error
    at new RuntimeError (C:\Users\P\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gltf-pipeline\node_modules\cesium\Build\CesiumUnminified\index.cjs:17022:11)
    at C:\Users\P\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gltf-pipeline\lib\compressDracoMeshes.js:269:15
    at ForEach.meshPrimitive (C:\Users\P\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gltf-pipeline\lib\ForEach.js:239:21)
    at C:\Users\P\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gltf-pipeline\lib\compressDracoMeshes.js:143:13
    at ForEach.object (C:\Users\P\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gltf-pipeline\lib\ForEach.js:44:21)
    at ForEach.topLevel (C:\Users\P\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gltf-pipeline\lib\ForEach.js:63:18)
    at ForEach.mesh (C:\Users\P\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gltf-pipeline\lib\ForEach.js:230:18)
    at compress (C:\Users\P\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gltf-pipeline\lib\compressDracoMeshes.js:142:11)
    at C:\Users\P\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gltf-pipeline\lib\compressDracoMeshes.js:59:14
    at tryCatcher (C:\Users\P\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gltf-pipeline\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\P\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gltf-pipeline\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:547:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\P\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gltf-pipeline\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:604:18)
    at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (C:\Users\P\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gltf-pipeline\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:641:10)
    at _drainQueueStep (C:\Users\P\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gltf-pipeline\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:97:12)
    at _drainQueue (C:\Users\P\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gltf-pipeline\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:86:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\P\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gltf-pipeline\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:102:5) {
  message: 'Error: Draco encoding failed.'
}
```

Do you have any idea to solve it?
Appreciate

I'm trying to make my glb files smaller